# How to change property of usercontrol dynamically in loop

Tags: c#, user-controls

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoY0D.png)I have problem that I am going to work with usercontrol in loop. In other word II want to change usercontrols property, but I cant. So I have usercontrol named ***ucProperty*** and in it many labels. I have called all of them differently such as ***LblNameModel*, *LblImageName*, ...** In my form there are many usercontrols - *ucProperty1,2,.8* and now I want to change their properties (*LblNameModel, LblImageName,..*) dynamically and in loop.
I try this:

```
int i = 1;
foreach (Control contrl in this.Controls) 
{
   if (contrl.Name == ("ucProperty" + i.ToString())) 
   {
      contrl.LblNameModel = "Model" + i.ToString();
      contrl.LblImageName = "image" + i.ToString() + ".jpg";
      i++;
   }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh34o.png) LblNameModel isnt accepted

But it doesnt work. My problem is properties as LblNameModel after ***contrl.*** isnt accepted to programm.
How I can change the properties in loop

and in my usercontrol `ucProperty` there is the code:

```
public string LblNameModel
{
    get { return lblNameModel.Text; }
    set { lblNameModel.Text = value; }
}
```

[this is next result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1Y8q.png)

Comment: Simply indent code snipptes by 4 spaces and leave an empty line between text and code to have them formatted as code.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must filter and cast to your user controls

```
using System.Linq;

...

foreach (var uc in this.Controls.OfType<MyUserControlType>()) 
{
   string number = uc.Name.SubString("ucProperty".Length);
   uc.LblNameModel = "Model" + number;
   uc.LblImageName = "image" + number + ".jpg";
}
```

If you simply loop through the controls, you get a loop variable typed as `Control` and you are not able to access properties specific to your user control. The `OfType<T>` extension method (namespace `System.Linq`) does both, filter and cast.

I assume that all of these user controls are named as `ucProperty<number>`. Otherwise add the check

```
if (uc.Name.StartsWith("ucProperty"))
```

Note that your approach with `i` has a problem if the user controls do not appear in the right order. I.e. If the `foreach` yields `"ucProperty4"` but `i` is `3` then this control will be skipped.

Comment: LblNameModel is used as Text in ucProperty. In it there are so many text properties so I have called them differently

Comment: and the code isnt working `contrl.LblNameModel.Text = "Model" + i;`

Comment: Thanks for advices! But my problem is about its properties, selfmade LblNameModel is underlined with red color because of error. And to my main question I added new image link, please can you see it?[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh34o.png)

Comment: I try it and for some reason now `foreach` is in error [this image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1Y8q.png)

Comment: First error: This is because `contrl` is of type `Control`. You must use `.OfType<ucProperty>()`. Only like this you will be able to see the label properties. The second error is because one pair of parentheses **()** is missing. There are the parentheses of the foreach plus the one after OfType: `foreach (var uc in this.Controls.OfType<MyUserControlType>()) `.

Comment: And you don't need `ToString()`. In `"Model" + i`, the variable `i` is automatically converted to `string`.